# Python client socketio cannot connect to nodejs server socketio

Tags: python, python-socketio

I am trying to connect python client using python-socketio with nodejs express server using socketio. I am able to connect python client with python server using python-socketio. I have already verified the versions and according to [version chart](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#version-compatibility) it should work.

In NodeJS, I am using "socket.io": "^4.7.4"
In Python, I am using "python-engineio==4.8.2" and "python-socketio==5.11.0"

## Server Code

```
// Server Code
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { createServer } from 'node:http'
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";
import cors from 'cors'

//App Varaibles 
dotenv.config()

//intializing the express app 
const app = express();

//using the dependancies
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("user disconnected");
    });
});

//exporting server
module.exports = server;
```

```
// Running Server
require("dotenv").config();
const server = require(".");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

//Listing to the app and running it on PORT 5000
server.listen(PORT, async () => {
   console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

## Python Client

```
# Python client
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@sio.event
def connect():
    print('connection established')

@sio.event
def my_message(data):
    print('message received with ', data)
    sio.emit('my response', {'response': 'my response'})

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')

sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
sio.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

can you dump the sid's of socket client from both server and client and see if its matching.